# Convergence of this infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> I want to show that $$(i) \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2+1)^2} \text{ and } (ii) \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{2k!}{(k!)^2}$$ converge by direct comparison test.

$(i)$: It holds $$\left|\frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2+1)^2}\right|=\frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2+1)^2}\leq \frac{2k^2+1}{(2k^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{2k^2+1}\leq\frac{1}{2k^2}\leq\frac{1}{k^2}$$ and since $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}$ converges, $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2+1)^2}$ also converges.

Does $$\left|\frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2+1)^2}\right|=\frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2+1)^2}\leq \frac{k^2}{(2k^2)^2}=\frac{k^2}{4k^4}=\frac{1}{4k^2}\leq\frac{1}{k^2}$$ also work?

$(ii)$ It holds $$\left|\frac{2k!}{(k!)^2}\right|=\frac{2k!}{k!\cdot k!}=\frac{2}{k!}$$
and since $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}$ converges, $2\cdot\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}$ and, therefore,  $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{2k!}{(k!)^2}$ also converges.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. We don't need to take absolute value.

Comment: This one $\frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2+1)^2}\leq \frac{k^2}{(2k^2)^2}$ holds but is not so straightforward, therefore the first mode is more clear.

Comment: Another way $\frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2+1)^2}\leq \frac{k^2-1}{(2k^2-2)^2}=\frac{k^2-1}{4(k^2-1)^2}=\frac{1}{k^2-1}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your (i) looks fine. But are you sure that for (ii), the series is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2.k!}{(k!)^{2}}$ and not $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^{2}}$? If it is the former, then your argument is fine, but if it is the latter, then you can use Stirling's approximation first followed by comparision.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, my series above is correct